# Xamarin: Bind one to another property in Style

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

I want to bind the Property WidthRequest to HeightRequest.

```
<Style TargetType="Frame" >
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="200"/>
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="{Binding HeightRequest}"/>
</Style>
```

So WidthRequest should have the value 200

Thank you :)

Comment: The `Setter` class has no bindable properties, and doing what you suggest would only make sense if `HeightRequest` was bound and was a dynamic value, rather than a static value, but you can't bind these properties, so this is a non-starter. Maybe if you explain what your desired end result is, someone can suggest a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do this in the code behind instead

```
public int HeightRequest { get; set; }

public int WidthRequest
{
    get
    {
        return HeightRequest;
    }
}
```

Comment: No I want to do this in the style section. Maybe I have to tell the style, that the DataContext are the own properties?